# How to avoid missing web push notifications while connecting to comet server

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, comet

I am wondering how to make sure a client doesn't miss push events while a page is being loaded or while they are connecting to the comet server.

For example, consider this timeline:

```
...
Request web page
.
Receive response
.
render page
.
execute javascript to connect to comet server
.
connection established
+
+ (receiving comet events)
+
Request another web page
.
Receive response
.
execute javascript to connect to comet server
.
connection established
+
+ (receiving comet events)
+
```

Obviously during the periods of time marked by a +, the client can receive the events coming from the comet server.  However, during the other times, there is no connection, so how will the user receive events that occur during these times?

Does anyone have any design patterns or architecture recommendations to make sure the events are not missed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a per-session message queue that the comet call reads from.  New events go into the queue and are there waiting when the client connects.  Depending on your architecture and scale, this can be a simple queue in the web app itself, a table in a database or a separate message queue.  You can delete them when they are delivered.

Answer (score 0):

### Generic Solution

As you are using a Comet server, make the client flag as "seen" each event it receives.

### Problem

If each client needs to respond to each notification, the traffic to your server may increase significantly. So, your server performance and network might get affected.

Other things, as event ordering might be considered for your solution.

### Solving the problem

The solution you have to adopt will depend on how critical is for your application the awareness of such events. If the client is able to work as expected even missing some of those events, consider a more relaxed solution.

1. Answer each event instantly

Whenever you receive an event from the server, ask server to flag it as "seen". If the server has events sent and not flagged as seen, make sure to resend them to the client. Becareful not to process the same event more than one time (on client-side) due to network latency (when your server sends the same event a second time before receiving the acknoledgement the first has arrived).

1. Relaxed approach

When your client receives an event, storage it as the "last event received". Whenever your client reconnects, ask server to send again those missed events since the last you have stored. If you lose track of which one was the "last event received", make sure your server retransmission starts from a point which will make sense for your client

---

These ideas might be implemented using a queue on the Comet server, but be sure to implement it correctly. If the order of those events are important, you must assure it on your implementation. Be sure not to create giant queues or indefinetly many of them. Consider other aspects too.

Hope I helped.